# Selenium WebDriver selecting from scope (IWebElement)

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is there a way to select elements **inside** already obtained IWebElement.
Im trying to do this via C# binding (RemoteWebDriver) but

```
findElem.FindElements(By.CssSelector(someStmt))
```

returns all elements from page (not from inside findElem)

Comment: Jim's answer is entirely correct, so your example code should work without an issue. To help us to help you, you should provide some example HTML that helps show the issue and show the structure of the page you are working with, along with what elements are returned and are not. I would also verify that `findElem` is actually an `IWebElement` and not a `IWebDriver` of some kind.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That is exactly the behavior of `IWebElement.FindElement` and `IWebElement.FindElements`. For most locators, including `By.CssSelector`, this works exactly as expected. The one exception is that using `By.XPath`, you need to prepend a "." to scope the XPath search to the current element. The WebDriver project's integration tests include tests for exactly this functionality. Without further context, like some example HTML that demonstrates the issue, further diagnosis is impossible.

Comment: You mean, that if i want to locate element in iside someone, i need use XPath for selecting all elements? html code is simple - is a ul with sub-ul inside lis.

Comment: No, you've completely misunderstood my answer. I only mentioned XPath in my answer because using XPath without understanding the XPath spec can lead to the behavior you describe; all other location strategies should behave as expected. The code you posted above in your question **should** work. Determining why it doesn't will require much, much more information than you've provided. That functionality isn't globally broken for every user of WebDriver for every website they're automating.

Comment: @JimEvans is the definitive source for questions involving C# and WebDriver.

Comment: Thx, after reading tests source i found my fault. Root of evil are in misunderstanding ByChained mechanism